# uploadify saving results in database

Tags: php, database, scope, uploadify

I am new to PHP. here is my code to save results of form to database and uploaded file name.I am using uploadify to upload files.
Here i have 2 problems.

1. file saves on its location in mozila but do not works for chrome.

   coded goes here.

   ```
    if (!empty($_FILES)) {

     $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name']; 
     $picAd= $_FILES ['Filedata']['name'];
   ```

   // to change same file name

   ```
   $picAd=rand(0,1000)."_".rand(0,1000)."_".$picAd;
        $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
   ```

   // this line works ok for all browsers

   ```
     $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
   ```

   this line not works for chrome

   ```
    //   $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $picAd; <<Error for chrome


    if( move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile)){                       // 4
     echo true;
     }else{
   echo false;
    }
   ```

   saving results to database .

   ```
        static $picAd;
       if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

      //  varibles
     $uname=$_REQUEST['userName'];         
     $pw=$_REQUEST["pw"];
     $email= $_REQUEST["email"];
     $twit= $_REQUEST["twit"];
     $user="user"; 
     if($picAd != ""){
     $q="insert into users values(Null,'$user','$uname','$pw','$email','$twit','$picAd')";
   mysql_query($q);
   mysql_close($dbc);  }
       }
   ```

Here i am not getting the value of $picAd in database its value goes NUll.

Comment: Did you googled it ? There is a lot of good scrpit and examples/tutorials about that ;)

Comment: yah but there wasn't any according to my need if u have one kindly share me a link.

Comment: Are "all" your other values being inserted into DB? `Null,'$user','$uname','$pw','$email','$twit'` and why are you using `static $picAd;` ? Are you using/taking this from a seperate class?

Comment: yes other values are saving properly.
i do not declare it out side the condition then it gives error unknown varible.

Comment: I have a form and a uploadify button i want form data and file name get saved in database.

Comment: No there was mistake in it values are not saving as value of $picAd is coming null.